# Confluence plugin import external attachments

Tags: java, confluence

I'm creating a plugin for confluence to import pages (title, body) and file assets (pdf and images).

I'm using PageManager to save the page and saving/creating a page is pretty straight forward but adding a attachment I'm finding dificult to understand how to do it as there is almost no information online that I can find how to do it.

Does anyone know how to set an attachment to a Page object form an inputStream or a `byte[]`?
The `page.setAttachments()` takes a list of Attachment object but if I try to create a attachment object it doesnt take either an inputStream or a byte array.

```
PageManager pageManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(PageManager) as PageManager
Page page = pageManager.getPage(8290525l)
URL url = new URL("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg");
InputStream bufferIn = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

---

Edit:

```
PageManager pageManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(PageManager) as PageManager
ArrayList<AttachmentResource> attachResources = new ArrayList<AttachmentResource>()

def page = pageManager.getPage(8290525l)
URL url = new URL("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg");
InputStream bufferIn = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

DefaultSaveContext context = new DefaultSaveContext()
context.setUpdateLastModifier(true)


AttachmentManager attachmentManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(AttachmentManager) as AttachmentManager
Attachment attachment = new Attachment("2454.png", "image/png", bufferIn.getBytes().length, "", false)
attachmentManager.saveAttachment(attachment, null, bufferIn)

page.addAttachment(attachment)
pageManager.saveContentEntity(page, context)
```

Comment: What version of the API are you using?

Comment: Confluence 5.10.4

Comment: Haha, well then, their [Api Docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/5.10.4/com/atlassian/confluence/pages/AttachmentManager.html#saveAttachment-com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Attachment-com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Attachment-java.io.InputStream-) are lying.

Comment: there is an alternative way. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [FileUploadManager](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/5.10.4/com/atlassian/confluence/pages/FileUploadManager.html) to upload the data and add the attachment (it looks like you are actually using Groovy, so I will too):

```
PageManager pageManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(PageManager) as PageManager
Page page = pageManager.getPage(8290525l)

URL url = new URL("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg");
InputStream bufferIn = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

FileUploadManager uploadManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(FileUploadManager) as FileUploadManager
AttachmentResource attachment = new InputStreamAttachmentResource (bufferIn, "2454.png", "image/png", bufferIn.getBytes().length)
uploadManager.storeResource(attachment, page)
```

Comment: and yes you are correct I am using groovy :) (good spot you are definetly a veteran)

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attachment content at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) at com.atlassian.confluence.pages.DefaultAttachmentManager.saveAttachments(DefaultAttachmentManager.java:161) at .....  ..... at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.saveAttachment(Unknown Source) at com.atlassian.confluence.pages.AttachmentManager$saveAttachment.call(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please edit your question and show your latest code.

Comment: I found the correct answer, your example works but it's missing "setContainer" on the attachment

Comment: How does this work? BufferedInputStream doesn't have a getBytes() method!
Should I make a HEAD request first to the URL to find out the number of bytes? How can an InputStream know the filesize before downloading all data?!

Comment: @dokaspar, in Groovy it sure does: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html